# nested if then statement, proper way to handle

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub btn_Click
Dim intAnswer as Integer
If txtAddress<>"" Then
intAnswer=Msgbox "Did you want to save", vbYesNo
    If intAnswer=vbNo Then 
Else
    do things
End If
End Sub
```

Notice the second `Then` statement is blank, I want it to go to the else statement. My brain is mush & I told myself initially do a `SELECT CASE` but I can't figure it out that way. I ended up doing the below & am not sure if that's proper procedure/recommended.

```
Dim intAnswer as Integer
If txtAddress<>"" Then
intAnswer=Msgbox "Did you want to save", vbYesNo
    If intAnswer=vbNo Then GoTo Start
Else
    GoTo Start
End If
Exit Sub
Start:
do things
```

Comment: I clarified, I didn't think it was necessary to elaborate every angle as that was out of the context of my concern

Comment: Well, it is important for me to understand what it is to give you a proper answer ;) And now you have changed `this` to `txtAddress` :)

Comment: So, if `txtAddress = ""` then you do the same thing as if `msgbox = vbNo`?

Comment: Yes hessr17. I want them both to go to the Else statement where a long list of `do things` is at. Your answer used the GoTo so I am assuming my second section of code in the initial question is recommended. I was under impression you shouldn't use GoTo's if you can help it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a much shorter way:

```
If txtAddress<>"" Or Msgbox("Did you want to save", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        'Do things
End If
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, if `txtAddress<>""` evaluates to false it still needs to `do things`. I thought I had clarified that, but I see how the code can be a bit misleading, I can change it if needed. `do things` is multiple lines of code I don't want to repeat

Comment: @greggmcfg: see my update. not sure I now understand your question, therefore not sure it solves it... can you explain in words what should be done under which circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
If txtAddress="" and msgbox "Did you want to save?", vbYesNo = vbNo Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf txtAddress <> ""
    'do Other Things
Else 'vbYes
    'do Last Set of things
End If

Exit Sub

Start:
do things
```

Comment: This is indeed another way to clarify, problem is it will ask you to save no matter what which I don't want. I only want it when something is IN a textbox. I am thinking a nested if & goto is indeed the proper solution now

Answer (score 0):

I tend to over-think things & furthermore I am learning so I made my this more confusing then it needed to be. I wanted to understand the concept of nested if's so I didn't advise what I was trying to do. I basically wanted to check if a form was filled in, since I only know what a new/unused one looks like I was basing it on that info. Below is what I needed:

```
Private Sub btn_Click
If txtAddress<>"" Then
    If Msgbox("Did you want to save", vbYesNo)=vbNo Then Exit Sub
End if
```

I want to give Peter Albert the 'answer', but his code always did the msgbox, where clearly in my code it didn't. I'm an idiot & wrote my code wrong in the first place, so ignore me